# TFS Updating EDMX after Database Deploy

Tags: entity-framework

I have set up build and deploy for my database projects and application project.
Both are working fine Independently. I want to update my edmx on application side after my database deployment is successful. So if there is any changes that were made in database side has not been updated on application side will be found.

Is there a way to do this in TFS using automated build process?

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are EdmGen and EdmGen2 tools that you can try.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/edm-tools-options-part-1-of-4.aspx

Comment: I could generate EDMX but not with all other settings. Like we are using EF 6 in our application and i only want to create EDMX with store procs. I also want to use the custome tool template while generating edmx. Is this possible?

Comment: if you are able to generate EDMX file, you are 50% there. The rest will be running EF T4 templates. You can do that using command lines: http://romiller.com/2013/05/15/running-ef-t4-code-generation-templates-from-command-line/

Comment: So after generating EDMX, i have to run this comandline tool from my project in order to use T4 code generation template?

Comment: I think i got bit off the track. I have edmx, then i used the code generation tool but it is not creating the poco classes for my store procs. I am using VS 2013, EF 6.0 with SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I am able to generate EDMX but not the way i want. I want to generate EDMX so that it matches to the edmx generates using VS. Pragmatically generated edmx does not have any function imports that are attached to Store Procs. the CSDL section comes out empty always. Do i have to create those entry for Function Imports using code or there is other way.